# jQuery hover method fires on multiple elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover

I have a hover method that is targeting multiple images, when you hover an image it should add a preview icon only on that hovered image, but it's happening on every element, I'm new to Javascript/jQuery and can't find a way of doing it, can someone help me out please?

This is my actual **jQuery** code:

```
// Make images smaller
$('.card').find('p > img').css({
  'width': '160px',
  'height': '118px'
}).parent().css('text-align', 'center');

// Add preview icon into DOM
$('.card').find('p:last-child').prepend("<img class='preview-icon' src='http://www.iconsfind.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/20151116_564931d273df6.png' width='80' height='80' />");

// Add style to our preview image
$('.preview-icon').css({
  'position' : 'absolute',
  'z-index' : '99999',
  'left' : '50%',
  'top' : '50%',
  'bottom' : 'auto',
  'right' : 'auto',
  'transform' : 'translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%)'
}).hide();

// On hover add/remove style
$('.card').find('p > img').hover(function() {
  $('.card').find('p > img').css({
    'opacity' : .2,
    'transition' : 'all 0.2s',
    '-webkit-transition' : 'all 0.2s',
    'cursor' : 'pointer'
  });

  $('.preview-icon').show();
}, function() {
  $('.card').find('p > img').css({
    'opacity' : 1,
  });

  $('.preview-icon').hide();
});
```

**Update v1**

So now it's working but if you hover over an image and then hover over the preview icon that appears, it doesn't bind the images, they work like two different ones (try the code using Chrome dev tools inside the website above):

```
// Make images smaller
$('.card').find('p > img').css({
  'width': '160px',
  'height': '118px'
}).parent().css('text-align', 'center');

// Add preview icon into DOM
$('.card').find('p:last-child').prepend("<img class='preview-icon' src='http://www.iconsfind.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/20151116_564931d273df6.png' width='80' height='80' />");

// Add style to our preview image
$('.preview-icon').css({
  'position' : 'absolute',
  'z-index' : '99999',
  'left' : '50%',
  'top' : '50%',
  'bottom' : 'auto',
  'right' : 'auto',
  'transform' : 'translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%)'
}).hide();

// On hover add/remove style
$('.card').find('p > img').hover(function() {
  $(this).css({
    'opacity' : .2,
    'transition' : 'all 0.2s',
    '-webkit-transition' : 'all 0.2s',
    'cursor' : 'pointer'
  });

  $(this).closest('.card').find('.preview-icon').show();
}, function() {
  $(this).css({
    'opacity' : 1
  });

  $(this).closest('.card').find('.preview-icon').hide();
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are executing the following inside the hover handlers

```
$('.card').find('p > img')
```

This is finding all of the images all over again, instead of using the one that is hovered over, or off.  Instead of repeating this selector, use `$(this)` instead.

It also looks like you are appending the preview-icon to the card.  So to access the related preview-icon.

```
$(this).closest('.card').find('.preview-icon').hide();
```

Comment: Hi @Taplar, thank you for you comment, I tried using $(this) and it works fine, except that it's breaking my preview-icon image.

Comment: When you hover the image it appears a preview icon I added through jQuery, when using $(this) it applies correctly on each element but that preview icon is not working correctly, I need to add a $(this).parent().parent().show(); but works in a weird way.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can try adding in the topic website this code, then hover over an image and when the preview icon appears hover over it, it starts flickering (I'm adding the new code in the topic).

Comment: hover(), if you read the API, binds in the same manner as a mouseenter and mouseleave http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: Using "$(this).css({" and " $(this).closest('.card').find('.preview-icon').show();" targets correctly, the flicker disappeared but it's not "binded", like you can hover both instead of working like one image.

Comment: Ah, well I'm just going off of the code in the question.  Without seeing a live example I can only do so much, ;).  Fixing to log for the day so maybe others can help further.

Comment: Thank you @Taplar, problem is I'm applying it in a live website (the one in the topic), so I'm using Google Dev console to add it), sorry.

Comment: `$('.card').find('p > img:not(.preview-icon)')` help with that?

Answer (score 0):

You're targeting descendant `p > img` elements from every `.card`, not just the one that has been hovered.

`$('.card').find('p > img').css`

should be

`$(this).css`

You can read more info [here](http://html-tuts.com/jquery-this-selector/).

Comment: Hi @Ryan Gee, thank you for you comment, I tried using $(this) and it works fine, except that it's breaking my preview-icon image.